# Efficiently transpose/explode spark dataframe columns into rows in a new table/dataframe format [pyspark]

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, explode

How to efficiently explode a pyspark dataframe in this way:

```
+----+-------+------+------+
| id |sport  |travel| work |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 1  | 0.2   | 0.4  | 0.6  |
+----+-------+------+------+
| 2  | 0.7   | 0.9  | 0.5  |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

and my desired output is this:

```
+------+--------+  
| c_id | score  |  
+------+--------+  
| 1    | 0.2    |  
+------+--------+  
| 1    | 0.4    |  
+------+--------+  
| 1    | 0.6    |  
+------+--------+  
| 2    | 0.7    |  
+------+--------+  
| 2    | 0.9    |  
+------+--------+  
| 2    | 0.5    |  
+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you could put your 3 columns in an `array`, then `arrays_zip` them and then `explode` them and unpack them with `.*`, then `select` and rename unzipped column.

```
df.withColumn("zip", F.explode(F.arrays_zip(F.array("sport","travel","work"))))\
  .select("id", F.col("zip.*")).withColumnRenamed("0","score").show()

+---+-----+
| id|score|
+---+-----+
|  1|  0.2|
|  1|  0.4|
|  1|  0.6|
|  2|  0.7|
|  2|  0.9|
|  2|  0.5|
+---+-----+
```

You can also do this without arrays_zip(as mentioned by cPak). Arrays_zip is used for combining arrays in different dataframe columns to struct form, so that you can explode all of them together, and then select with .* . For this case you could just use:

```
df.withColumn("score", F.explode((F.array(*(x for x in df.columns if x!="id"))))).select("id","score").show()
```

Comment: thanks, this works.  What about a generic way to do this with N columns?

Comment: the F.array(*), * can take a list of columns so you could do like, F.array(*(x for x in df.columns if x!=id))

Comment: Why do you need `arrays_zip`? Just `explode(array(*cols))` works

Comment: @CPak initally the question had 2 other columns as well, thats why I had arrays_zip in my logic, but yes you are right. arrays_zip is for exploding arrays that are in different columns.

Comment: Ah, okay, makes sense